# If line contains a word then return text between characters "

Tags: php, regex

If line contains a word then return text between characters "

```
<a href="index.php?sheet=2362327&sign=1" alt='This is funny alt' class='some test classes'>
```

I need to get url index.php?sheet=2362327&sign=1 if sign= is found.

P.S

I have found a way to get a line if word is found: `/^.*\bsign=\b.*$/m`

And to get content between 2 characters: `(?<=")(.*)(?=")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2662457 ;-)

Comment: @TomasCreemers you should read more than one of the answers

Comment: @rjdown: I know regex is a valid way to parse partial HTML. I just saw a chance to refer to an epic answer and took it. Hence the ";-)", :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=")[^"]*\bsign=\b[^"]*(?=")
```

You can just club the two to get your result.

Comment: This did the work, I think i will read a book about regex, thats my weak spot at the time ;// 5 minutes till i can accept your answer!